# How costly is re-rendering svgs in React?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg

I have a world clock component which shows the current time in different time zones similar to this - https://backstage.io/storybook/?path=/story/plugins-home-components-headerworldclock--default.

This component get re-rendered every second so I was wondering if I added an `<img src={location/of/svg/flag}/>` does the flag source get re-rendered every second or does it get cached/memoize (currently storing the flag svg locally but want to eventually move them to s3). If it gets fully re-rendered every second, how costly is this operation?

The final component would look something like

Timezone
Flag
Current Time

with 6+ different time zones in a multi level grid. The alternative is to decouple the static `Timezone` and `Flag` with the changing `Current Time` but I have not found a way to do it with keeping the current styling.

Comment: I don't imagine rendering SVGs being any more expensive than rendering any other xml-like tags, e.g. HTML tags, e.g. JSX. If your question is about performance this is easy enough to audit in the browser. If your question is about React performance, well, React generally only rerenders only what it needs to, but if any component is rendering unnecessarily, ***and there's an issue with that***, there are tools you can use to help indicate to React that a rerender may be unnecessary.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.